# Exception when passing gulp callback directly to promise

Tags: javascript, callback, gulp, promise, del

I've defined gulp task 'clean-code' and function 'clean' as below

```
gulp.task('clean-code', function (done) {
 var files = ...;
 clean(files, done);
});

function clean (path, done) {
 del(path).then(done);
}
```

and got error

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --color --gulpfile /Users/[path to project]/Gulpfile.js clean-code
[11:45:04] Using gulpfile /Users/[path to project]/Gulpfile.js
[11:45:04] Starting 'clean-code'...
[11:45:04] Cleaning: ./.tmp/**/*.js,./build/**/*.html,./build/js/**/*.js
[11:45:04] 'clean-code' errored after 8.68 ms
[11:45:04] Error
    at formatError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/Users/[path to project]/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
    at /Users/[path to project]/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
    at finish (/Users/[path to project]/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (/Users/[path to project]/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
```

But when I've refactored function 'clean' in the following way everything is ok

```
function clean (path, done) {
  var f = function () {
    done();
  };
  del(path).then(f);
}
```

I don't understand where is the difference and why wrapping done with f make the task working

Comment: If I had to guess - `done` takes arguments - the first of the arguments is an `Error` to signal abrupt completion. This is the node callback convention. If you call `done` after `then` and `del` has a return value - it will fail. If you use bluebird promises you'd do `del(path).nodeify(done)` to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) library, it's worth nothing that the Promise returned for the `del` function actually returns an argument `paths`. You can verify if this argument is present like this:

```
function clean (path, done) {
    del(path).then(function(paths) {
        console.log(paths);
        done();
    });
}
```

In your code:

```
function clean (path, done) {
    del(path).then(done);
}
```

will forward the `paths` argument to the done function, which will interpret it as an error argument causing your application to crash. By calling `done()` yourselves, no arguments are forwarded and the task will be properly executed.